# AngularJS model changes not shown in GUI after directive changes it

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I am having an issue where I have a model:

```
<div ng-model="currentAudio">...</div>
```

I have a button (within and ng-repeat in the div of the model above):

```
<button ng-click="changeStuff(myAudioObj)">My Button</button>
```

When I click the button, change stuff changes the currentAudio model and my GUI displays the change (I show the id of the object).

But my issue is when the directive I have changes "currentAudio" then I try to change it again with my button, the change doesn't show.

```
MyApp.directive('audioplayer', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('ended', function (evt) {
                PlayNextAudio(scope);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

My PlayNextAudio(scope) method assigns scope.currentAudio = myCurrentAudio, which works fine as it goes through the list, but when I stop this and try to click my button it doesn't change anymore.

It's as if it is on some other thread and gets stuck on the directive thread.  My console output shows the button correctly assigning to my currentAudio model.

EDIT:  I've added:

```
scope.$apply(function () {
    scope.changeCurrentAudio(scope.myCurrentAudio);
});
```

But no luck.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: can you please setup a plunker, not getting the relationship between: PlayNextAudio & changeCurrentAudio or provide complete code or plunker may be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ng-repeat creates child scopes and therefore your `myCurrentAudio` isn't part of your intended scope anymore.

To solve this there is the ["*always use the dot in ng-model*"](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) rule.

```
<div ng-model="audio.current">...</div>

<button ng-click="audio.changeSong(audio.myAudioObj)">My Button</button>
```

Here is an example without the dot: http://plnkr.co/edit/GKf7WhnnItVNeBpvSB0F?p=preview
And here is an example with the dot: http://plnkr.co/edit/aESrHtuSH9cd9ljyQAfH?p=preview

If this doesn't work for you please provide the complete ng-repeat html source or a plnker example.